# MySQL Query Help: Giving Two Different Results

Tags: mysql

My Sample Data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e29e54/7

My goal is to find a COUNT and SUM of sold items as well as quoted items.

```
SELECT
clients.`id`,
COUNT(IF(clients.`paid_to_date` != clients.`policy_date`, `premium`, 0)) AS sold_count,
SUM(IF(clients.`paid_to_date` != clients.`policy_date`, `premium`, 0)) AS sold_client,
COUNT(clients.`id`) AS quote_count,
SUM(clients.`premium`) AS quote_client,
users.last_name, users.first_name
FROM `clients`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `clients`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE clients.`policy_date` IN (
    SELECT policy_date FROM clients WHERE month(`policy_date`) = '2' AND year(`policy_date`) = '2018'
)
GROUP BY `users`.`last_name`
ORDER BY users.`id` ASC;
```

Both sold_count and quote_count return the same number, 3, as if "clients.`paid_to_date` != clients.`policy_date`" is not working. It should return 2 results for user_id = 1, John Smith.

This query returns 1 results for user:

```
SELECT  id, client_number, policy_number, agent_name, paid_to_date, policy_date
FROM `clients` WHERE `user_id` = '1' AND month(`policy_date`) = '2'
AND year(`policy_date`) = '2018'
AND `paid_to_date` != `policy_date`
ORDER BY `policy_date` ASC
```

Any advise on how to get the sold_count and sold_clients IF statement to work correctly would be greatly appreciated!!

I would of thought for the first query
   Sold Count = 2, instead of 3.

The sold_client is correctly adding the 2 results but the count is not correct.

Basher

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: There isn't even a column in the resultset named `quote_total`!

Comment: @eggyal it should of said quote_count, I've corrected it!

Comment: I've added sample data via SQLfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6680/2

Answer (score 0):

So simple.. what was I thinking. here's my solution:

```
SELECT clients.id,
SUM(IF(clients.`paid_to_date` != clients.`policy_date`, 1, 0)) AS sold_count,
SUM(IF(clients.`paid_to_date` != clients.`policy_date`, `premium`, 0)) AS sold_client,
COUNT(clients.`id`) AS quote_count,
SUM(clients.`premium`) AS quote_client, users.last_name, users.first_name
FROM `clients`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `clients`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE clients.`policy_date` IN (
SELECT policy_date FROM clients WHERE month(`policy_date`) = '2' AND year(`policy_date`) = '2018'
)
GROUP BY users.`last_name`
ORDER BY users.`id` ASC;
```

Changed first SUM() to just sum the result count.